# VBA PageSetupXL4M not formatting properly pages on Excel 2010

Tags: excel, installation, excel-2010, vba

I found this method on Internet and thought it could be used in my code, since i have many pages to format and it takes tremendous amount of time:

```
Public Sub PageSetupXL4M(Optional LeftHead As String, Optional CenterHead As String,  Optional RightHead As String, _
Optional LeftFoot As String, Optional CenterFoot As String, Optional RightFoot As String, Optional LeftMarginInches As String, _
Optional RightMarginInches As String, Optional TopMarginInches As String, Optional BottomMarginInches As String, _
Optional HeaderMarginInches As String, Optional FooterMarginInches As String, Optional PrintHeadings As String, _
Optional PrintGridlines As String, Optional PrintComments As String, Optional PrintQuality As String, Optional CenterHorizontally As String, _
Optional CenterVertically As String, Optional Orientation As String, Optional Draft As String, Optional PaperSize As String, _
Optional FirstPageNumber As String, Optional Order As String, Optional BlackAndWhite As String, Optional Zoom As String)

Const c As String = ","
Dim pgSetup As String
Dim head As String
Dim foot As String

If LeftHead <> "" Then head = "&L" & LeftHead
If CenterHead <> "" Then head = head & "&C" & CenterHead
If RightHead <> "" Then head = head & "&R" & RightHead
If Not head = "" Then head = """" & head & """"
If LeftFoot <> "" Then foot = "&L" & LeftFoot
If CenterFoot <> "" Then foot = foot & "&C" & CenterFoot
If RightFoot <> "" Then foot = foot & "&R" & RightFoot
If Not foot = "" Then foot = """" & foot & """"

pgSetup = "PAGE.SETUP(" & head & c & foot & c & _
  LeftMarginInches & c & RightMarginInches & c & _
  TopMarginInches & c & BottomMarginInches & c & _
  PrintHeadings & c & PrintGridlines & c & _
  CenterHorizontally & c & CenterVertically & c & _
  Orientation & c & PaperSize & c & Zoom & c & _
  FirstPageNumber & c & Order & c & BlackAndWhite & c & _
  PrintQuality & c & HeaderMarginInches & c & _
  FooterMarginInches & c & PrintComments & c & Draft & ")"
Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro pgSetup

End Sub
```

The problem is that it is not formatting pages at all (maybe the problem is that I'm using Excel 2010?).
I call the XL4 Page Setup in this other piece of code:

```
    Dim Sheets_Select

For Each sheet_select In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sheet_select.Select

    With sheet_select
        .Cells(1, 1).Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(1, 1).Value = "type-no. " & TypeNo
        .Cells(1, 1).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=17).Font.FontStyle = "Standard"
        .Cells(2, 1).Font.Bold = True
        .Cells(2, 1).Value = "specification point: " & SpecName
        .Cells(2, 1).Characters(Start:=1, Length:=28).Font.FontStyle = "Standard"
    End With

    With sheet_select
        .Rows.RowHeight = 12
        .Columns.ColumnWidth = 3.43
        .Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 8
        .Cells.NumberFormat = "0.0"
        .Cells.Font.Name = "Arial"
        .Cells.Font.Size = 9
        .Cells.HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Columns("A:A").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .Rows("1:9").HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
    End With

    '###### L o g o ######
        sheet_select.Cells(2, 27).Select
        sheet_select.Pictures.Insert(apppath + "\Script\logo.bmp").Select
        Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth 0.35, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        Selection.ShapeRange.ScaleHeight 0.35, msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft

    '###### P a g e   S e t u p ######
    PageSetupXL4M Orientation:="""xlLandscape""", LeftMarginInches:="""0.6""", RightMarginInches:="""0.6""", TopMarginInches:="""0.6""", BottomMarginInches:="""1""", HeaderMarginInches:="""0.5""", FooterMarginInches:="""0.5""", PaperSize:="""xlPaperA4"""
    Application.ExecuteExcel4Macro pgSetup
    '.LeftHeader = Header(1, 1)
    '.CenterHeader = Header(1, 2)
    '.RightHeader = Header(1, 3)
    '.LeftFooter = Header(2, 1)
    '.CenterFooter = Header(2, 2)
    '.RightFooter = Header(2, 3)

Next sheet_select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that code is designed to bypass the problem of multiple commands being sent to the printer for each worksheet.

In Excel 2010, you can use normal Excel 2010 VBA Print setup code along with the new features:

```
application.printcommunication = false
' PageSetup code here
application.printcommunication = true
```

that will force all the commands to be sent to the printer in one batch, and you won't need the old XL 4 macro methods

(thanks to Google) there is more [here](http://www.edugeek.net/blogs/pico/755-excel-2010-printer-fails-communicate.html)

Comment: Thanks Philip, can I ask you if the calculation time is as short as with XL4 macros?

Comment: it should certainly be close, except for the issue with the PageHeadings as outlined on [MS Answers - Excel Macro will not change header information](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/excel-macro-will-not-change-header-information/43cfb783-9b6e-42cf-b935-4a2752b147a9)

Comment: I tried and tried... And it looks like somehow, if I set application.printcommunication to false, the page won't be correctly set up :(